# How to return 0 in a cell if one or two cells are empty from nested if statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Day!This is is the scenario. I have three columns A,B and Value. Return 1 if B is greater than or equal to A. Return 0 if B is less than to A. Return empty or NULL cell if both cell A&B are empty. I tried this simple formula but it always return 1 if B>=A. See sample below.

[image]

Please help.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this by using this formula

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2,B2),IF(B2>=A2,1,0),"")
```

If you have some other answers please share.

Comment: even this would do `=IF(COUNT(A2:B2),--(B2>=A2),"")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`=IF(B1>A1,1,IF(B1<A1,0,IF(AND(A1="",B1="")=TRUE(),"")))`

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the below formula, please let me know is this you expected?

Hope it will help you to get an idea and modify it as per your

**=IF(OR(A2="",A2=0,B2="",B2=0),"",IF(B2>=A2,1,IF(B2<=A2,0,"")))**

[image]

Please Change only the B2<=A2 from B2'<'A2 as you mentioned. Because it doesn't appear in the screen when posting an answer due to '<' mark and remove '' this mark too when changing it.